# Connecting Excel 2013 to SSRS 2012 to use as a datasource

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I am trying to set up a Data Source using an Excel 2013 file for the information to feed a report.

Here are the steps I'm following:

1. Click on Data Source
2. Add new Data Source
3. Change Type to ODBC
4. Select Edit for Connection String
5. Choose Excel as System Data Source Name
6. Select Use Connection String- (First issue- find Excel, but does not give me an option for XLSX files.) Only XLS files.

Any suggestions.

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ODBC Connection String use the following:

Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\yourspreadsheet.xlsx;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";

For more info on connection strings, I can recommend this site.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007/

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem so I download the *AccessDatabaseEngine.exe* from [This](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255). After installation, it gave support to .xlsx file. Still if you not found that option of Microsoft Excel Driver with .xlsx support go to C driver --> Windows --> SysWow64 --> odbcad32.exe [run this] you will find here.